How to batch copy images from one folder to another from an Excel file?
I’m looking for an effective way to batch copy varying files from a fixed folder to varying folders.
What I mean by this is: I’m planning to put all of my product photos in one ‘master folder’ and would like to easily create new folders for every time a client asks for specific photos or for every time I have to make a new catalog with the new articles.
I’d preferably like to do this with Excel VBA.
The first column of my Excel sheet would be the path of the required files in the master folder, the second column would be the destination path.
How do I achieve this in VBA?
Thanks!
I've tried this code but it isn't working:
Sub FileCopy()

Dim SourcePath As String
Dim DestinationPath As String
SourcePath = "D:\Pictures\Test\10787 000.jpg"
DestinationPath = "D:\Pictures\Test\Target\10787 000.jpg"

FileCopy SourcePath, DestinationPath

End Sub


Carefull, your Sub has the same name as the command to copy the files (both are FileCopy). The sub name will hide the FileCopy command and you get a compile error "Wrong Number of arguments".

Loop through the cells to read the paths & file names, assign these to the variables SourcePath and DestinationPath
